# Magento 2 : Show Out of Stock Swatch Options On Configurable Product Page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, option

I want to show `outofstock` swatch options on the configurable product even if the options is outofstock and the main configurable product is also out of stock.

I want to show that swatch options with disable functionality.

Comment: Which Magento version are using ?